# Foundation._GenericObjCError.NilError from core data batch delete

Tags: swift, core-data, ios9, batch-delete

I am trying to use batch delete feature of core data. I have an entity named Car. That entity has a column name modelNumber as `Int`. I want to delete all cars which has modelNumber older than 2000. Here is my code:

```
func deleteCarsOlderThan(modelNumber: Int) {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "modelNumber <= %@", NSNumber(int: modelNumber))

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Car")
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
    deleteRequest.resultType = .ResultTypeCount
    do {
        let result = try self.fhirManagedObjectContext.executeRequest(deleteRequest)
        try self.fhirManagedObjectContext.save()
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

While executing this code, control goes to catch block and it gives an error says: `Foundation._GenericObjCError.NilError`. My fetch request is working well as if I use:

```
    let olderCars = self.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
```

it returns me an array of older cars. I don't know where I am doing wrong.
I am using iOS9 for this purpose.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the entire error instead of just a small snippet.

Comment: This is all what I get as an error.

Comment: The console must be outputting more than that.  I have never seen any error in Xcode put out just one line.  I would suggest casting your error to an `NSError` and printing out its `userInfo` and seeing if there are underlying errors.

Comment: Nope, he's right. That is the entire error. I'm seeing the same thing when doing a simple fetch. No idea what's going on.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra I am also getting the same error. Its `userInfo` dictionary is empty. Don't know what's wrong here.

Comment: Bit of a zombie resurrection :) What is the full output of the error?  Maybe open a new question?  Also look at Christopher's answer below.

Comment: Related: [What is Foundation._GenericObjCError.NilError?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55640917/3939277)

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: While `self.fhirManagedObjectContext` is non-optional, it's probably returning nil from Objective-C.

The error you observed is generated by Swift's Foundation bridging runtime. (See the source code [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/5d293ab9d214b4997e235f53f60fcecc91b3513d/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/NSError.swift).) This occurs when an Objective-C method with an error pointer returns a failure value (`NO` or `nil`), but no actual error was passed back via the `NSError` pointer. This could either be the result of a bug in Core Data or, more likely, a nil managed object context that when using Objective-C method dispatch causes the method to appear to return `NO`.